# How could I obtain the same Hilbert transform result as Matlab does with FFTW?

Tags: c, signal-processing, fft, absolute, fftw

I need to calculate the Hilbert transform and get its absolute number from my signal.
I installed the FFTW and followed [these YouTube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZ_NMdIbOYs&t=211s), both worked good.

However, I implemented the Hilbert Transform as the video did, I didn't obtain the value as same as Matlab calculated.

I've read some of the people who solved this problem by just using the FFT and doing other calculations, but they didn't give the answer clear enough.
Could anyone provide me several lines of code which based on the FFTW so that can let result become same to Matlab calculated result?

Here is the Hilbert transform code which I followed the video:

```
void hilbert(const double* in, fftw_complex* out)
{
    // copy the data to the complex array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] = in[i];
        out[i][IMAG] = 0;
    }
    // creat a DFT plan and execute it
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    // destroy a plan to prevent memory leak
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    int hN = N >> 1; // half of the length (N/2)
    int numRem = hN; // the number of remaining elements
    // multiply the appropriate value by 2
    //(those should multiplied by 1 are left intact because they wouldn't change)
    for (int i = 1; i < hN; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] *= 2;
        out[i][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // if the length is even, the number of the remaining elements decrease by 1
    if (N % 2 == 0)
        numRem--;
    else if (N > 1) {
        out[hN][REAL] *= 2;
        out[hN][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // set the remaining value to 0
    // (multiplying by 0 gives 0, so we don't care about the multiplicands)
    memset(&out[hN + 1][REAL], 0, numRem * sizeof(fftw_complex));
    // creat a IDFT plan and execute it
    plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    // do some cleaning
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    fftw_cleanup();
    // scale the IDFT output
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] /= N;
        out[i][IMAG] /= N;
    }
}
```

My main program to calculate:

```
pi16Buffer = (int16 *)pBuffer;
        //int16* ch1Buffer; 
        //int16* ch2Buffer;
        
        double* ch1Buffer = NULL;
        double* ch2Buffer = NULL;
        fftw_complex result[N] ; // output array
        
        // Allocate size to ch1 and ch2
        ch1Buffer       = (double*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof(double));
        ch2Buffer       = (double*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof(double));
        
        //ch1ch2ch1ch2... fulfill the buffer
        for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++)
        {
            ch1Buffer[i] += (double)pi16Buffer[i*2];
            ch2Buffer[i] += (double)pi16Buffer[i * 2 + 1];
        }

        // here hilbert on the whole ch2
        hilbert(ch2Buffer, result); //hilbert(inputarray, outputarray)

        for (i = 0; i < u32Size; i++)
        {
            if (ch1Buffer[i] > max1)  //Find max value in each segs of ch1 and ch2
                max1 = ch1Buffer[i];

            if (abs(result[i]) > max2)
                max2 = abs(result[i]); // Calculate the absolute value of hilbert result;

    
        }
        Corrected = max2 / max1; //do the signal correction
        free(ch1Buffer); //free buffer
        free(ch2Buffer);

        
        
    }
    return Corrected;
```

Comment: It is difficult to correct your code if we don't see it. Moreover, you should use more reliable sources than youtube videos, for example [wikipedia-Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform)

Comment: Hi @Damien, I attached my code now, thanks for the notification.

Comment: Note that the matlab function puts the original values on the real part, and put the Hilbert transform value on the imaginary part. You could provide a very simple input (4 or 8 elements), with your output and matlab output

Comment: Hi @Damien, thanks for the reply, but I'm not really get your thought. Could you kindly write down an example such as code for more clear explanation? Thanks!

Comment: I don't use fftw, but my own FFT functions. I could try to provide an example with a simple DFT function. However, I don't have matlab, and it would help me to have an example of good input/output

Comment: Thanks maybe I can take a look!

Comment: @Damien Could you provide me your solution? I am almost the last step but be stuck in this issue almost 3days...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some difficulty to understand your code.
Here is my test code, on a simple N=4 case.
It should work at least for all even sizes of the input. To be checked with odd input.

This code calculates the analytic signal. The `hilbert` function of matlab does the same.

The real part of it corresponds to the input real signal.
The Hilbert transform corresponds to the imaginary value.

The principle is to insure that the value of its FFT for negative frequencies is zero.
This is obtained by a simple windowing in the frequency domain.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

// Analytic signal calculation
// The real part of it corresponds to the input real signal
// The hilbert transform corresponds to the imaginary value

void print (complex *x, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf ("(%lf, %lf) ", creal(x[i]), cimag(x[i]));
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

void fft4 (complex *x, int n, int inversion) {
    complex t0, t1, t2, t3;
    t0 = x[0] + x[2];
    t1 = x[1] + x[3];
    t2 = x[0] - x[2];
    if (!inversion) t3 = I * (x[1] - x[3]);
    else t3 = -I * (x[1] - x[3]);
    x[0] = t0 + t1;
    x[2] = t0 - t1;
    x[1] = t2 - t3;
    x[3] = t2 + t3;
}

#define N 4

int main() {
    const int n = N;
    complex x[N] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    complex y[N] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    
    fft4 (y, n, 0); // direct FFT size 4
    
    print (x, n);
    print (y, n);
    
    for (int i = 1; i < n/2; ++i) y[i] *= 2.0;
    for (int i = n/2+1; i < n; ++i) y[i] = 0.0;
    
    fft4 (y, n, 1);     // inverse FFT
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) y[i] /= n;  // normalisation
    print (y, n);       // print analytical signal

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And sorry for that I should give more detail about my code and what I am going to do. I'm using a dual channel DAQ card with data stream mode. The channel 2 (`ch2Buffer[i]`, `[i]` is segment) will obtain acoustic wave which is N-shape so that's why I want to use Hilbert transform to "flip" the negative part of the N-shape signal to positive and get its absolute number. There will be 8320 data points in every segments of channel2. Any suggestion to integrate your code to my data?

Comment: My code focuses on obtaining exactly the same result as the matlab function, as you requested. The resulting signal has no negative frequencies. What is missing? Did you get good results with matlab code?

Comment: Maybe the problem is a misunderstanding of the `result`. The signal obtained by Hilbert transformation is not result but the imaginary part of it. This would mean that you should use `max2 = abs(result[i][IMAG]);`

Comment: Hi @Damien, I didn't try your code yet because the function generator is not with me now, I just ask how could I put your code in my main program?

Comment: Concerning your hilbert function, I cannot see a difference between your programme and mine. Maybe something hidden. Again, I suspect that the problem is not there, but how you are using the result, see my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks! Read it. Hope it works in tomorrow. One more question, what is the `N`mean in mine and your code? I heard that means data point, such as 8320, but not sure.

Comment: Yes, `N` is the number of data points per block.

Comment: Just for a remain, what I mentioned the “negative ” not meaning the negative frequency, which is the negative amplitude part of a sine wave signal.

Comment: could you demonstrate how to use your code in my program? Because I want to compare which one has the fastest calculation, thanks!

Comment: My code here only have a FFT of size 4. Your code for the hilbert stuff is quite good. Two possibilities of improvement : 1. Calculate `f=1/N' and multiply by `f` instead of dividing by `N`. Maybe useless if compiler smart enough. 2. You build FFT module for each block, might be costly if many blocks. Do it once and reuse the same FFT module for each block. I don't have fftw here.

Comment: Hi @Damien Could you give me some example code to demonstrate the second way you provided because I am not fully understand how to realize it. Thanks!

Comment: I am not used to ftw. At least I guess you should avoid `fftw_cleanup` as useful information is removed by this cleaning function and must be built again (as far as I understand). Besides, if you have a working code and want to improve it, it is better to post it on se.codereview site. Pay attention then to post a independent working programme that people will be able to test directly.